# XOR Encryption issues... Total Beginner

Tags: c++, encryption

As a total beginner I have been attempting to write some code for XOR encryption in C++

The problem I am having is that when decrypted only half of the message actually is correctly translated

If anyone could tell me what is going wrong and also how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it

I have also attached what is shown on the console displaying the error 
Qoóß®ó»¥Á╝©®50¤ä┌Ð╬┘ð╝
non-encrypte[_í®┐┐¡½®╠Press any key to continue . . .

My code is as follows;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char string[] = "non-encrypted_message";
    char key[] = "A";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(string); i++)
    {
        string[i] = string[i] ^ key[i];     //Performing the encryption with XOR operator
        cout << string[i];                  //Output of encrypted message

    }
    cout << "\n";

    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(string); j++)
    {
        string[j] = string[j] ^ key[j];
        cout << string[j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't link images in your question. Please copy and paste the text.

Comment: You should also know about the terminating character in C-strings and decide whether you want it to be changed by the encryption or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` has a size of only 2 (including the terminating character), yet you index it in your loops, causing it to go out of bounds. Either make it a single `char` and don't index it, or make sure the array is large enough. I suggest using `std::string` or `std::array` or `std::vector` which good debuggers will bounds-check for you.

Comment: Thanks very much this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Declare key as char and don't use index on it.

```
char key = 'A';
...
string[i] = string[i] ^ key;
```